# What is the residue of $\frac{\sin \frac{1}{z}}{z^2+a^2}$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to expand everything into a power series but I'm not sure how to get the answer out of that. Every corresponding product seems to be a coefficient of $1/z$

Comment: Are you sure that there is a residue at $0$? Is $\sin(1/z)$ holomorphic at $z=0$?

Comment: @MiloMoses That function is *undefined* at $z=0$. So what? Does that prevent it from having a residue there?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos At $z=\frac{1}{2\pi k i}$ we have that $\sin(z)=0$. This means that there the set of zeros around $z=0$ is not discrete, which means that this is not a homomorphic function around $z=0$.

Comment: @MiloMoses That doesn't answer my question. **Of course** that it is not holomorphic at $0$. It's not even defined at that point.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos From what I understand, a function can be holomorphic at a point even if it undefined, as long as it is the ratio of analytic functions (i.e $\lim_{z\to0}z^kf(z)$ exists for some $k>0$). For the function $sin(1/z)$, this limit does not exist for any $k$ (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: @MiloMoses You are mistaken. I suppose that you are thinking about meromorphic functions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah yes, I mixed up the terms in my head. I am sorry for the confusion.